# "Er fährt mit einem blauen Fahrrad zur Schule" Fahrrad accusative or dative case?

Tags: dative, accusative

I was learning German and stumbled across a "complete the sentence" question:

> "Er fährt mit einem _____ Fahrrad zur Schule" (blau)

Now, I thought that because the bike is being actively performed on *i.e.* being affected by the *fährt*, the *Fahrrad* would be accusative, so I thought the missing word was "*blaues*"

But apparently, the correct answer is "*blauen*" as *Fahrrad* is dative, not accusative. I'm confused why.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: (1) You wouldn't say "einem" if it were not dative. (2) The object of the preposition "mit" is always dative.

Answer (score 9):

after "mit" you always use "Dativ". Look at the "einem". That's screaming "Dativ" for you!

Answer (score 7):

Case in prepositional phrases is largely determined by the preposition involved. If it's *mit*, then the noun takes the dative, no questions asked; if it's *ohne*, it's the accusative.

(There are a small number of location-related prepositions that take *either* the dative or the accusative, depending on whether the entire proposition is about a *location* or a *direction*, eg. *auf* or *unter*, but otherwise the larger context is irrelevant for case after a preposition.)

Answer (score 1):

You’re thinking ‘something that is actively performed on’, i.e. an object. It is true, that if a verb takes an object and if that object is usually inanimate by nature then this object will typically be in accusative case in German:

> Er spielt *die* Rolle sehr überzeugend.

Verbs that have an accusative object like in the above example are called transitive. The verb *fahren* can also be transitive:

> Er fährt *ein blaues Fahrrad* zur Schule.

In English, a possible translation would be:

> He rides a blue bike to school.

However, *fahren* can be used in many different ways. The above emphasises the act of riding the bike and the destination (the school) is less relevant. Another way to use *fahren* is intransitively. In this case, there is no direct object and the main meaning shifts from steering/driving a vehicle to using a vehicle to get from A to B. A more reduced version but still perfectly valid version of your example sentence would be:

> Er fährt zur Schule.

Or even:

> Er fährt.

These in themselves are complete sentences using the intransitive meaning of *fahren.* As with most verbs, they can be expanded with various adverbials one of which designating the tool—here, the bike. When describing a tool with an adverbial, the usual way to do it is in a *mit* expression. *Mit* as a preposition governs dative, thus in your example sentence dative is the only possible choice:

> Er fährt *mit einem **blauen** Fahrrad* zur Schule.

Compared to the above, the focus here is centred more on *where* he is going with the additional information of *how* being optional.

---

Even without this in-depth analysis, the only possible choice given the small blank you have is *blauen* anyway: the indefinite article *einem* already makes it clear that the dative form is required.