# «Wir sind zur neuen Wohnung gefahren» Why 'zur neuen' (dativ) and not akkusativ?

Tags: grammatical-case, grammar-identification

In the sentence

> «Wir sind zur neuen Wohnung gefahren»

I think zur=zu +der, with der = die+dativ termination, and  neuen = neu+fem termination in dativ.

However, since we're fahren (wohin), shouldn't we have used akkusativ instead?

Comment: Regarding the dative feminine singular check [here](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/en/grammar/nouns-and-articles/declension/dative) please, _der_ is correct.

Comment: You're right about 'sind'. My bad. ;)  Yes, der is correct. That's not the point of my question... The point is why we use dativ, and not akkusativ.

Comment: I think this answers your question: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48298/er-f%C3%A4hrt-mit-einem-blauen-fahrrad-zur-schule-fahrrad-accusative-or-dative-case

Comment: The above question is about the case that goes with *mit*, not with *zu* as in this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The “wohin” rule that you are alluding is to for deciding whether to use accusative or dative with a two-way preposition. But “zu” is not a two-way preposition, it always goes with dative.

Comment: oh... Thanks. I didn't know that ;)